# Why does ImageButton quality blurs or reduces to worst?

Tags: java, android, imagebutton

My app has a ImageButton whose quality is too bad. The actual image dimensions are 4176*4176 (4176pixels) which looks completely fine when opened separately. But when I import this to android studio and assign it to a ImageButton, the quality of the image downgrades. I have been trying a number of ways to fix this but haven't succeeded yet. I'm completely new to Android Programming.I go to res/drawable then right click to create a new Image Asset and then specify the location which imports the png file.

Actual image: [image]
Image inside studio: [image]

Here is the code in activity_main.xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
android:gravity="center"
android:orientation="vertical">

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/police"
    android:layout_width="317dp"
    android:layout_height="295dp"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"

    android:background="@drawable/custom_button"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

Custom button code which calls the image:

```
<item
    android:state_pressed="true"
    android:drawable="@mipmap/pressed" />

<item
    android:drawable="@mipmap/defaultt" />
</selector>
```

Comment: Either don't use a scaleType, or make your width and height equal. Also, there's no way you'll ever need a 4kx4k image. Scale that down.

Comment: Still remains the same even with same width and height

Comment: 4176px*4176px is **much too high** a resolution for a button. It's even too high for a tablet background with a xxxhdpi density.

Comment: Since the image remained always blurry, I created this high res image expecting that it'll be crystal clear :p

Comment: 192px by 192px is more than enough for a button in drawable-xxxhdpi. You should actually read the Android design guidelines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are actually referencing the image like Launcher icon in `/mipmap` directory.

I suggest reducing the image size which you are only using it for `ImageButton` and placing it inside `/drawable` with the quality you want or maybe smaller than the current one instead of placing it inside `/mipmap` directory.

Also, I don’t actually see the reason of how `scaleType` helps in `ImageButton`. You may wanna remove that line too.

Comment: Check [here](https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screendensities) for how you should size your image for each different density-dependent drawable folder.

Comment: Thank you @TheWanderer Since I was taking the image from mipmap which lead to this issue. I actually even tried taking directly from drawable with some other image and the result was the same. But now when I chose some other image and imported to drawable and called it from there the quality was good this time. Isuee fixed :)

Answer (score 2):

I'd start by reviewing density independent pixels on Android. This is a good blog that covers the concept: https://www.captechconsulting.com/blogs/understanding-density-independence-in-android

The main issue is that your image (which is very high res) is getting compressed to fit inside of the image button. Typically, you would want to include image assets for different densities via different drawable resource directories (e.g., drawable-hdpi, drawable-xhdpi, drawable-xxhdpi).

However, these days, you can use vector drawables, which will reduce the need for having multiple assets for each density bucket, assuming you have the ability to generate SVG asset files: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/vector-drawable-resources

Comment: Yes I did use those drawable resources. But it seems that I'm not importing them properly. You can see that I call them from within the custom_button.xml file to get the image, I call from @mipmap/defaultt . The 'defaultt' folder has 5 different hdpi versions and when I view the xxxhdpi version from the folder, that's the best one there. However on importing, studio chooses the least hdpi version rather than the best xxxhdpi version. How do I specify exactly a particular version while importing?

Comment: The system selects the drawable that corresponds to each devices pixel density. Specifically, devices with higher pixel density will use higher resolution drawables. You could log your devices density to see which drawable is being used if you're curious. How are you generating your assets? If you are creating them with a vector design tool (e.g., Adobe Illustrator), it should be easy to export quality assets for each density bucket by scaling accordingly:

https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screendensities

Comment: Taking the image directly from drawable fixed this. This issue was there even with drawable folder but after I changed the image to some other high quality image and then took from drawable, it got fixed . Thank you for the help